# how to check for brackets outside two quotes in a String

Tags: java, performance

i have for instance a String : `if('{' == '{'){`.
i would want it to not detect the brackets inside the `' '`
but i do want it to detect the one at the end which is not inside the quotes
what the best way of doing i tried to loop through all chars but is there a quicker method?

Comment: Are you trying to write a parser/lexer of your own?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ in creating a simple scripting language

Comment: @pufferenco that job is much harder than parsing each token on your own. I suggest you have a look at ANTLR (https://www.baeldung.com/java-antlr), it's a java library which is done exactly to create your own scripting language and that allows you way more power for less much headache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply remove those braces altogether or replace them with something meaningful. To just remove those `'{'` and `'}'` characters from the string then you could do it like this using the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method which accepts a [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex), for example:

```
// Original String:
String strg1 = "if('{' == '{'){";
    
/* Apply change and place into a new string (strg2) 
   so to keep old string original (in strg1).    */
String strg2 = strg1.replaceAll("'\\{'|'\\}'", "");
    
// Display the new String strg2:
System.out.println(strg2);
```

The Console Window will display:

```
if( == ){
```

The regex `"'\\{'|'\\}'"` used above basically does the following:

Replace All instances of `'{'` OR `|` All instances of `'}'` within the string with Null String `""` (nothing). Within the Expression, the curly braces are escaped `\\{` because they have special meaning within a Regular Expression and by escaping those characters informs regex processing that we mean literal character.

If you want to replace those `'{'` and `'}'` character combinations with something meaningful like specific values then you can replace those items separately, for example:

```
// Original String:
String strg1 = "if('{' == '}'){";
int value1 = 10;  // An open brace ( '{' ) will be converted to this value
int value2 = 24;  // A close brace ( '}' ) will be converted to this value
    
/* Apply change and place into a new string (strg2) 
   so to keep old string original (in strg1).    */
String strg2 = strg1.replaceAll("'\\{'", String.valueOf(value1))
                    .replaceAll("'\\}'", String.valueOf(value2));
    
// Display the new String strg2:
System.out.println(strg2);
```

The console window will display:

```
if(10 == 24){
```

In the above code you will of noticed that the [String#valueOf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) method was used within the replacement section of the [String#replaceAll()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replaceall.htm) method. This is because the replacement values we want to use were declared as `int` data types and the **replaceAll()** method requires String as a replcement argument therefore we take those `int` values and convert them to String type.